# Does the order of a foreign key attributes mean anything?

Tags: sql

Say for example I have a table called **ACCOUNT** and another called **TRANSACTIONS**.

If **ACCOUNT** has primary key **[num, type]**:

What is the difference between these two statements...

This is a foreign key on **TRANSACTION**: **[num, type] < ACCOUNT[num, type]**

and

This is a foreign key on **TRANSACTION**: **[type, num] < ACCOUNT[num, type]**

Note the "**<**" symbol is meant to mean this symbol[image]

Comment: uh buddy...if the answer is useful then please accept the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Foreign key sequencing matters when the database indexes have to retrieve the data from the tables.

In case you have table as below:

```
key | code | value
 a  |  1   | val 1
 a  |  2   | val 2
 b  |  1   | val 3
 b  |  2   | val 4
 c  |  1   | val 5
 c  |  2   | val 6
```

where primary key is key and code then when the database will search, it will search for key first thus reducing the result set, then it will retrieve data to the second column that is Code. In case u reverse the order u get a non optimized solution.

also i think the data base tries to link the columns with foreign key in the similar manner.

therefore it does matter.

In case u do have a doubt, try to create 2 dummy tables which are linked to each other via foreign key. in case it gives an error try to Google that error code. you will get a proper explanation.

Comment: I agree, good point. Here are examples: http://appsdba.com/techinfo/composite_index.pdf

Comment: I see, well how about this hypothetical situation... Say for example **[num, type]** was a foreign key on **ACCOUNT[num, type]**, is there any reason that **[type, num]** would NOT be a foreign key on **ACCOUNT[num, type]**?

Comment: The data base will not be able to index the second table with the foreign key if it was allowed. It is sort u can say that internal forcing to make u let it work properly..:P

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand, are you saying [type, num] would not be a foreign key on account[num, type]?

Comment: as per me yes...the foriegn key mapping should map as per sequence...Have u tried the reverse sequencing..??